# SQL Like is accepting only "context"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi I have problem in my DB Query.

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`knihy`) 
                      WHERE `stav` = 1 
                      AND (Autor1 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                      OR Autor2 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                      OR Autor3 LIKE '$vyraz' 
                      OR Autor4 LIKE '$vyraz') 
                      ORDER BY `id` desc LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ");
```

The problem is that, when I am searching for example for "lorem" and I have in my table for example in row Autor1 content: "lorem ipsum" nothing will be found. But if I am searching for lorem ipsum there will be found those one field. Where is problem please?

Comment: add for LIKE params '%' around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the right syntax for LIKE:

```
Autor1 LIKE '$vyraz'
```

Should be:

```
Autor1 LIKE '%$vyraz%'
```

Without the wildcards, you're just doing an exact match.

Comment: Remember that using an initial wildcard will throw out your index.  Be careful!

Comment: @AlainCollins - you know, that hadn't ever occurred to me. That's something new I've learned today!

Comment: what you mean with "initial wildcard will throw out your index" ?

Comment: @Geril - if you're using an index on the column, it won't work if you have a wildcard at the start of your LIKE. Your index contains all the values in that column, sorted - so if you have a wildcard at the start of your LIKE, the database will still have to search the column. You'll still get the results, but the performance won't be as fast.